# display date in textbox from gridview/database in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, entity-framework-6

I develop one web form by using ASP.net, I want to select the row and display that row data into web form but the date cannot display in the textbox of type DateTime, someone helps me to sort out this issue

**ASP.Net Code**

```
<div class="col-4">
    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Birth Date"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
    </br>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
</div>
<div class="col-8">
    <asp:GridView ID="studentGrid" runat="server"
        DataKeyNames="Id"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="StudentGrid_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowSelectButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

**c# Code**

```
protected void StudentGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        selId = Convert.ToInt16(studentGrid.SelectedDataKey[0]);

        if (selId > 0)
        {
            using (var ctx = new dbTestEntities())
            {
                var oldObj = ctx.tblStudents.Find(selId);
                if (oldObj != null)
                {
                    txtBirthDate.Text = oldObj.BirthDate.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: what shows in the textbox? Have your stepped through the code and look at what oldObj comes back with?

Comment: @JobesK nothing shows in textbox, only dd-mm-yyyy shows in textbox cause it's textmode="date"

Comment: when I try to set a date with any label it becomes successful

Comment: IIRC, you see how you get the ID with `studentGrid.SelectedDataKey[0]`? I think you have to do something like that. Use the grid, or probably the row and then `FindControl`. This has probably been answered if you search for 'FindControl in grid row' or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date format of the textbox with TextMode="Date" is "yyyy/MM/dd" but it stores date with default time like 2021/25/09 12:00:00 AM so the date is fetched from database but not able to set to the textbox, So we need to set the proper format of date like

```
    txtBirthDate.Text = String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", oldObj.BirthDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

The data keys is always referenced by name.

So, from the grid it is

```
 GridView1.DataKeys[5]["ID"]
```

(Get the 5th row datakey value of "ID")

In your case, you have the selected row, so you need this:

```
selId = Convert.ToInt16(studentGrid.SelectedDataKey["ID"]);
```